# Matlab plot ksdensity without first storing its arguments

Tags: matlab, plot

In MATLAB, if I want to plot density of a variable `V` I have to do

```
[x, y] = ksdensity(V);
plot (y, x);
```

If I do `plot(ksdensity(V))`, it only plots `x` and not `x` Vs `y`.

Is there an easier alternative to give `ksdensity()` as an argument to `plot()` and do the same job as `plot(y, x)`?

Comment: What's wrong with `plot(y, x)`?

Comment: @Dan I have multiple variables, to be plotted in same plot. So I want to do something like, `plot(density_of_variable_1,'color1'); hold on; plot(density_of_variable_2,'color2'), ..` so on. If I go plot(y, x) route, I will need to type in twice as many extra variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refactor it into a function that takes in `V` and plots `y` vs `x`:

```
function h = plot_ksdensity(V, varargin)
    [x, y] = ksdensity(V);
    h = plot (y, x, varargin{:});
end
```

using `varargin` means you will still have access to `plot` options like colours. `hold on` will also still work because this just calls the regular `plot` function.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no. If you don't specify explicitly the outputs, a function will return always the leftmost one from output parameter list. To convince yourself about that, create the function `ftest()` somewhere in your MATLAB path:

```
    function [x, y] = ftest( )

            x = 1;
            y = 2;

    end
```

then call it in the Command Window without specifying the outputs

```
    >> ftest()

    ans =

         1
```